# pythonで中心座標を与えられたクラスタ点を3Dでランダムに生成する

Tags: python, random

私は、pythonを使って中心座標(0,0,0)とした球内にクラスタ点を生成したいです。しかし、参照される記事はjavaやC#ばかりで理解することができないです。どんな助言でもいいので、助けてくれると嬉しいです。また、数学もそこまで詳しいわけではありません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 球の半径がRだとすると、「-Rから+Rの範囲の乱数を３個発生させて、それをx,y,z座標とした点が球内ならクラスタ点として採用する」という操作を必要な数の点が得られるまで繰り返せば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 要望に合うか分かりませんが関連してそうなキーワードで検索するとこれらあたりでしょうか。[ステージ2-4: クラスタリング、3次元グラフ描画演習...](https://ie.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~tnal/2013/info4/dm/stage2-clustering.html), [K-Meansによる色のクラスタリング](https://aiqlab.com/tech_blog?id=204), [scikit-learnでクラスタリングしてみる](https://www.lanches.co.jp/blog/5696), [pythonでクラスタリングと表示](https://pepper.is.sci.toho-u.ac.jp/pepper/index.php?python%A4%C7%A5%AF%A5%E9%A5%B9%A5%BF%A5%EA%A5%F3%A5%B0%A4%C8%C9%BD%BC%A8)